# Spark AVRO S3 read not working for partitioned data

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, avro, spark-avro

When I read a specific file it works:

```
val filePath= "s3n://bucket_name/f1/f2/avro/dt=2016-10-19/hr=19/000000"        
val df = spark.read.avro(filePath)
```

But if I point to a folder to read date partitioned data it fails:

val filePath="s3n://bucket_name/f1/f2/avro/dt=2016-10-19/"

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 HEAD request failed for '/f1%2Ff2%2Favro%2Fdt%3D2016-10-19' - ResponseCode=403, ResponseMessage=Forbidden
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.handleServiceException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:119)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy7.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:414)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1397)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$12.apply(DataSource.scala:374)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$12.apply(DataSource.scala:364)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:364)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:132)
at com.databricks.spark.avro.package$AvroDataFrameReader$$anonfun$avro$2.apply(package.scala:34)
at com.databricks.spark.avro.package$AvroDataFrameReader$$anonfun$avro$2.apply(package.scala:34)
at BasicS3Avro$.main(BasicS3Avro.scala:55)
at BasicS3Avro.main(BasicS3Avro.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: it looks like an authentication error, the service responded with 403. Maybe you should check the policy associated with  the bucket.

Comment: But same credentials works when I access the specific file. Also, I can list content of the folder using aws command line.

Comment: ok, let me try to reproduce it locally...

Comment: just try it with: val filePath="s3n://bucket_name/f1/f2/avro/dt=2016-10-19" - without ending slash

Comment: @devsprint Same error  :|

Comment: Which version of spark are you using? I'm not able to reproduce the issue using spark 2.0.0 with spark-avro 3.1.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

what does the newer, maintained, s3a client report?

Comment: Sorry I can you rephrase your questions? @Steve Loughran